# Displaying custom controller data in visualforce page after onchange event

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

> I have a picklist containing names of records of an object, "Test_Script".When I select any option from a picklist("selectlist" & selectoption are used for implementing picklist),at onchange event the other fields related to that record name should be displayed on visualforce page.
>
> VF Page:

```
<h1>Choose Script:</h1>
<apex:selectlist value="{!selectedValue}" size="1"onchange="{!setValues}">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!scriptoptions}" />
                        </apex:selectlist>
                        <br/>
                        Executioner Name: 
                        <outputfield value="{!valueResult.executioner_name}"/>
                        <br/>Planner Name: 
                        <outputfield value="{!valueResult.planner_name}"/>
                        <br/>Reviewer Name: 
                        <outputfield  value="{!valueResult.reviewer_name}"/>
```

Controller:

```
public class ScriptAttributesController 
{

    public String setValues { get; set; }
    public List<Test_script__c> scriptListWithValues = [select name, id, Executioner__c, Planner__c, Reviewer__c from Test_Script__c];
    public static Test_Script__c valueResult=new Test_Script__c();
    public String selectedValue {get;set;}
    
    public void ScriptAttributesController()
    {
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getScriptoptions()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('select a value','select a value'));
        for(Test_Script__c s: scriptListWithValues )
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption(s.id,s.name));
        }
        return options;
    }
    
        public void setValues()
    {
        valueResult=[select name, id, Executioner__c, Planner__c, Reviewer__c, Iteration__c from Test_Script__c where name='selectedValue' limit 1];
    }
}
```

> I am not able to see value on screen on change og picklist value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that a getter is missing for your valueResult.

```
public Test_Script__c valueResult {get; set;}
```

and in the controller you can init the object.

Comment: Thanks, This removed the error. However, I am not getting how to show executioner__c, planner__c, reviewer__c etc fields of test script object  related to the SELECTED script in dropdown on screen. Can you please help